# Javascript set img src

Tags: javascript, image, src

I am probably missing something simple but it's quite annoying when everything you read doesn't work. I have images which may be duplicated many times over the course of a dynamically generated page. So the obvious thing to do is to preload it and use that one variable as the source all the time.

```
var searchPic;
function LoadImages() {
    searchPic = new Image(100,100);
    searchPic.src = "XXXX/YYYY/search.png";
    // This is correct and the path is correct
}
```

then I set the image using

```
  document["pic1"].src = searchPic;
```

or

```
  $("#pic1").attr("src", searchPic);
```

However, the image is never set properly in FireBug when I query the image I get `[object HTMLImageElement]` as the `src` of the image

In IE I get:

```
http://localhost:8080/work/Sandbox/jpmetrix/[object]
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Answer (score 119):

You should be setting the src using this:

```
document["pic1"].src = searchPic.src;
```

or

```
$("#pic1").attr("src", searchPic.src);
```

Answer (score 76):

#### Pure JavaScript to Create **`img`** tag and **`add attributes`** manually ,

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
var imageParent = document.getElementById("body");
image.id = "id";
image.className = "class";
image.src = searchPic.src;            // image.src = "IMAGE URL/PATH"
imageParent.appendChild(image);
```

---

#### Set src in **`pic1`**

```
document["#pic1"].src = searchPic.src;
```

or with getElementById

```
document.getElementById("pic1").src= searchPic.src;
```

#### j-Query to archive this,

```
$("#pic1").attr("src", searchPic.src);
```

Comment: document.getElementById("pic1") without #

Answer (score 8):

Instances of the image constructor are not meant to be used anywhere. You simply set the `src`, and the image preloads...and that's it, show's over. You can discard the object and move on.

```
document["pic1"].src = "XXXX/YYYY/search.png";
```

is what you should be doing. You can still use the image constructor, and perform the second action in the `onload` handler of your `searchPic`. This ensures the image is loaded before you set the `src` on the real `img` object.

Like so:

```
function LoadImages() {
    searchPic = new Image();
    searchPic.onload=function () {
        document["pic1"].src = "XXXX/YYYY/search.png";
    }
    searchPic.src = "XXXX/YYYY/search.png"; // This is correct and the path is correct
}
```

Comment: if you set src in onload() you get an infinite loop which hammers the server i.e. when src has been loaded it calls onload.

Comment: there is something else going wrong since a load event can only fire once. You can't get it to fire again by setting the source to the same image.

Comment: You are right, there are other SO articles which talk about weird caching problems when the "XXXX/YYYY/search.png" is a webcam pic or something that changes on the server side. They suggested that we change the link to "XXXX/YYYY/search.png?t=<thedate>". Your solution was nicest and cleanest so I combined the two and it hammered the server.

Comment: @DavidNewcomb Yikes! that's a tricky one. In in that case, I think I would ditch the new Image() part, and instead have two actual dom images- like a double buffer. hide image1, hide image2.  in an interval timer: set src on image1, and in image1.onload, show 1, hide 2. Interval fires: set src on image2. in image2.onload, show 2, hide 1. wait, interval fires: set src on image1. in image1.onload, show 1, hide 2- etc. etc...

Answer (score 7):

Also, one way to solve this is to use `document.createElement` and create your html **img** and set its attributes like this.

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
var imageParent = document.getElementById("Id of HTML element to append the img");
image.id = "Id";
image.className = "class";
image.src = searchPic.src;
imageParent.appendChild(image);
```

**REMARK**: One point is that Javascript community right now encourages developers to use document selectors such as `querySelector`, `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` rather than document["pic1"].

Answer (score 2):

```
document["pic1"].src = searchPic.src
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to construct a whole new image... the src attribute just takes a string value :-)

Comment: If the page is generated dynamically using javascript, you'll want the image downloaded when the page is loaded so you don't get an annoying delay the first time you create an element that needs it.  That's the reason for creating the Image object.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't very precise in my answer. I just meant to say that the src attribute takes a string, and totally forgot about the caching advantage of creating the `Image` on beforehand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
document["pic1"].src = searchPic.src;
```

The searchPic itself is your Image(), you need to read the src that you set.

Answer (score 0):

Your src property is an object because you are setting the src element to be the entire image you created in JavaScript.

Try

```
document["pic1"].src = searchPic.src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow! when you use `src` then `src` of `searchPic` must be used also.

```
document["pic1"].src = searchPic.src
```

looks better

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [WinJS](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/winjs) you can change the `src` through the `Utilities` functions.

```
WinJS.Utilities.id("pic1").setAttribute("src", searchPic.src);
```