# Canvas image change by changing src

Tags: javascript

I try to change a image by changing the image.src. 
But it doesn't work. When it is used in setInterval() function, it works.
I wan
t know WHY(?).

```
var imgE=new Image(); 
imgE.src="Ship.png";
window.onload=init;

function init () {
ctx=document.getElementById("can1").getContext("2d");
draw();
//setInterval(draw,100);
butE=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
butE[0].onclick=change;
butE[1].onclick=getback; 
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,500);
  ctx.drawImage(imgE,100,100,100,100);
}
function change() {
  imgE.src="Ship_d.png";
  draw();
}
function getback() {
  imgE.src="Ship.png";
  draw();
}
```

I have heard of 'preload of images before uses'. But I don't know exactly. 
Anyway the written below works. Then why don't they need the preload?
(Excuse my ignorance)

```
var imgE=new Image();
imgE.src="Ship.png";
var imgdE=new Image(); 
imgdE.src="Ship_d.png";
window.onload=init;

function init () {
ctx=document.getElementById("can1").getContext("2d");
draw(1);
butE=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
butE[0].onclick=change;
butE[1].onclick=getback; 
}

function draw(no) {
ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,500);
  if (no==1) {
    ctx.drawImage(imgE,100,100,100,100);
  }
  else ctx.drawImage(imgdE,100,100,100,100);
}
function change() {
draw(2);
}
function getback() {
```

draw(1);
   }

Comment: please add the html portion related to this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript set img src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232793/javascript-set-img-src)

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely because the image is not loaded in time.

Either preload the images needed before you use them or you need to use

```
imgE.src = "Ship_d.png";
imgE.onload = draw;
```

Comment: I added a second question relating your good answer by editing the original question.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking in your new question.