# How to set the src of an img tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function that is getting the values of other html elements and I want to pass those values to the image tag. How do I Pass that?

My Function is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitValues()
    {
        var firstname = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
        var lastname = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
    }
```

```
<img src="firstname=get_javascript_valuehere;lastname=get_javascript_valuehere;/>
```

Comment: java or javascript? besides, what you have posted is not a function, but a simple dom image element. Edit: the OP edited to java script

Comment: you make no sense, please rephrase your question and please provide some code.

Comment: Do you want to alter the `src` attribute in the `img` tag using js?

Comment: No, I want to get the entered first name and last name entered in the textbox and pass it to the image tag..

Comment: What is "passing it to the image tag" if it is not changing the `src` attribute? Please be more specific.

Comment: First Name and Last Name entered by the user in the text boxes and I want to pass it to the Img tag..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript set img src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232793/javascript-set-img-src)

Answer (score 2):

Put an id on your image tag and use the following:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = "firstname=" + firstname + ";lastname=" + lastname + ";";
```

That's at least what you've asked for, but I imagine there is more to this question if you'd like to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `.attr()` method to modify the attribute of an element.

```
function submitValues() {
    var firstname = $("[name=firstname]").val();
    var lastname = $("[name=lastname]").val();
    $("img").attr("src", "firstname=" + firstname + ";lastname=" + lastname + ";");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitValues()
{
    var firstname = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
    var lastname = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
    var img =  document.getElementById('fullName');
    img.setAttribute("src","firstname"+firstname+"lastname"+lastname+";");      
}
```

Add an id to the img to query it using the document.getElementById(), then set the src attribute using this code.

It should work.