# Only one image appears in an array of 3 images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

```
<img id="opeth"> </img>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gearpics = [];
        document.getElementById("opeth").innerHTML = gearpics;

    var prs = new Image();
    prs.onload = function() {
    };
    prs.src = src

    var prs2 = new Image();
    prs2.onload= function() {
    };
    prs2.src = src

    var prs3 = new Image();
    prs3.onload= function() {
    };
    prs3.src = src
function insert() {
    gearpics.push(document.getElementById('opeth').src = prs.src);
    gearpics.push(document.getElementById('opeth').src = prs2.src);
    gearpics.push(document.getElementById('opeth').src = prs3.src);
    }
</script>
```

This is my code. When I run it, and press the "Show pictures" button, only the third picture (id=prs3) appears. I want all of them to show up.

Comment: you are setting all 3 pictures to the same ID. The 3rd one is showing up because that's the last one being set to that ID. If you create 3 img tags and push each picture to a different ID, they should all show up

Comment: `</img?>` That's illegal html. img tags are singletons and cannot have any content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript set img src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232793/javascript-set-img-src)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same ID for your 3 pictures:

```
gearpics.push(document.getElementById('opeth').src = ...);
```

ID should be unique in HTML document.

Comment: Thank you. Adding different ID's to the pics worked! Cheers, mate!

Comment: Happy to be helpfull ;-) Don't forget to mark the question as solved.