# set path of img src by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not that much familiar with javascript/jquery. I want to put image path in img src. Is that possible to do that like we do in php or some other i need to use.

```
  <img src="path of file that will come from javascript/ajax" width="35" height="30" id="profile" class="profile img-circle" name="profile" data-original-title="Steve" alt="Steve">
```

I know in php it is quite easy.

```
  <img src="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>" width="35" height="30" id="profile" class="profile img-circle" name="profile" data-original-title="Steve" alt="Steve"></a>
```

I tried putting the same way we did in php like `<script>imgpath</script>` but it is not working.

Comment: This may be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232793/javascript-set-img-src

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/javascript-variable-inside-string-without-concatenation-like-php

Comment: @StephenC i checked that question but i dont understand the concept/logic. If you can put some light then it would be great.

Comment: The examples provided in the answers is just targeting the desired img, then replacing the src with whatever you decide to pass in.

Comment: I am trying to achive the same but it seems like something is not right. pic = "path of image" and $("#profile").attr("src", pic);