# Generate array of image in javascript inside <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make the background image in div tag and it has to change automatically, I already put the array of images inside the javascript, but the images is not showing when i'm run the site.The background should behind the menu header.

This is the div

```
<div style="min-height:1000px;position:relative;" id="home">
```

below of the div is containing the logo, menu and nav part.

```
         <div class="container">
          <div class="fixed-header">
              <!--logo-->
               <div class="logo" >
                  <a href="index.html">
                      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo mazmida" height="142" width="242">
                      </a>
               </div>
                <!--//logo-->
```

This is the javascript

```
 <script>
   var imgArray = [
    'images/1.jpg',
    'images/2.jpg',
    'images/3.jpg'],       

curIndex = 0;
    imgDuration = 2000;        



function slideShow() {
    document.getElementID('home').src = imgArray[curIndex];
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
    setTimeout("slideShow()", imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
```

Comment: there are few syntax errors , closing tag of div and there is not src tag for div which should be image element

Comment: the tag is already close, so i need to put the src tag inside the div?

Comment: @NagaSaiA already put the tag, it still same

Comment: It's not `document.getElementID`, it's `document.getElementById`, and a div does not have a src property.

Comment: nothing change still same @R.Schifini

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with your script. I've made a live JSbin example here:

https://jsbin.com/welifusomi/edit?html,output

```
  <script>
   var imgArray = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/02/Homer_Simpson_2006.png/220px-Homer_Simpson_2006.png',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/0b/Marge_Simpson.png/220px-Marge_Simpson.png',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png'
   ]; 

   var curIndex = 0;
   var imgDuration = 1000;        

  var el = document.getElementById('home'); 

function slideShow() {
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgArray[curIndex % 3] + ')';
    curIndex++;
    setTimeout("slideShow()", imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
  </script>
```

There are a few issues with your script:

- On the element since it's a div not an img, you need to set style.backgroundImage instead of src. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background for other attributes to related to background image CSS
- Also it's document.getElementById

Optimizations

- And you can use mod % trick to avoid zero reset
- Use setInterval instead of setTimeout

Further optimzations

- Use requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout/setInterval

I suggest getting familiar with your browser debugging tools which would help identify many of the issues you face.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementID('home').src = imgArray[curIndex]

You are targeting a div with an ID of home, but this is not an Image element (ie ,

But since you want to alter the background colour of the DIV,  then you use querySelector using javascript and store it in a variable, then you can target the background property of this div (ie Background colour).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I want it to be image not colour

Comment: yeah, changing image src is not an attribute of a div, but for an img element. I only said background-colour as an example of things that can be changed on a div.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the src property of a div, but divs do not have such property.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('home').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgArray[curIndex] + "')"
```

This changes the style of the target div, more precisely the image to be used as background.

Comment: Still nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to change the background image of the `div`, instead of `document.getElementID('home').src = imgArray[curIndex]` use 
`document.getElementById("#home").style.backgroundImage = "url('imageArray[curIndex]')";`

in JavaScript or

`$('#home').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageArray[curIndex] + '")');` in jquery.

Comment: I'm new to jquery, where should i put the jquery?

Comment: For jQuery put jQuery CDN between the head tag. And start working on it. To learn JQuery refer : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp .

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using setInterval

Please correct below syntax errors

1. document.getElementID to **document.getElementById**
2. .src attribute is not available on div tags
3. Create img element and add src to it
4. Finally use setInterval instead of setTimeout outside slideShow function

```js
 var imgArray = [
    'http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png',
    'https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.ySEgAgJIlDQsIQTu_MeoLwHaHa&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300',
    'https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.wBAPnR04OfXaHuFI9Ny2bgHaE8&pid=15.1&P=0&w=243&h=163'],       
curIndex = 0;
    imgDuration = 2000;        

var home = document.getElementById('home')
var image = document.createElement('img')

function slideShow() {
    if(curIndex != imgArray.length-1) { 
      image.src = imgArray[curIndex];
      home.appendChild(image)
      curIndex++;
    }else{
      curIndex = 0;
    } 
}
setInterval(slideShow,2000)
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;" id="home"></div>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JLKvME

Comment: those styles , I have used for reference, you can replace them with your actual css

Comment: did you create var home = document.getElementById('home')  to appendChild? not seeing errors on codepen and Run code snippet in my answer

Comment: syntax error , var image = document.createElement('banner')  should be var image = document.createElement('img') to create img tag

Comment: still same i put banner.img

Comment: var image = document.createElement('img') , please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232793/javascript-set-img-src