# I'm manipulating the height of an image using JavaScript, however, at first the image loads with original size and then the JavaScript is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below takes the height of the navigation (50px, this is important for later) and the height of the viewport then sets the max-height of the image to be viewport height minus navigation height.

I do this so that the image will always be fully visible, no matter how tall it might be. Unfortunately, this has a small drawback.

Whenever I refresh the page, for a split second I could see the image before the JavaScript height has been applied. After comparing the difference in height using Photoshop, I realized the difference is exactly 50px which is the height of the navigation. This makes it clear that the image uses the CSS rules for a split second before the JavaScript kicks in.

Now my question is this - can I make it so that the image doesn't get displayed until the JavaScript manipulation has been applied to the image?

CSS

```
.specific-image {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function fitImage() {
        var navHeight = $("nav.navigation").outerHeight();
        var viewport = $(window).height();
        $(".specific-image").first().css({"max-height":viewport-navHeight});
}
```

Comment: How are you adding the image? i guess directly in the HTML?

Comment: The image is not hard-coded. It's image path is saved in a database and then I dynamically display it using PHP - <img class='specific-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->image_file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />

Comment: try leaving the src attribute blank in the HTML and adding the url using javascript after you changed the css. ([https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232804/2633917](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232804/2633917))

Comment: try setting `display:none;` initially for that class and change it to `display:block;` in your `fitImage()` method

Comment: What Vijay Krishna suggested did work just fine. Could there be any drawbacks to using that?