# Display the correct firebase storage image in html using JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

So I have a loop which is displaying the user data as expected (this works fine):

```
database.once("value", function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    var r = document.getElementById('userTable').insertRow()
    var age = r.insertCell(0).innerHTML = snap.val().key;
    var aboutme = r.insertCell(1).innerHTML = snap.val().photourl;
})
```

The user image is stored in firebase storage like so (clicking into the folder which contains the image):

[image]

My user table looks like this:

[image]

With all the associated fields linked to that user under that and the photo_url holds the image path like:

```
user_photos/07KSLIkK2/D41FB90B444D-9979-22F86D69883F.jpg
```

Ive tried looking online but most of the answers or solutions are for android. Im pretty new to firebase.

So the question is how can i display the associated image from firebase for the user in the html table?

Thanks

Also, using:

`snap.val().key;` does not show that random generated number by firebase. just shows as undefined.

**UPDATE**

was having some difficulties so just for testing purposes i split the code up like so:

```
database.once("value", function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      var temp_photo = storageRef.child('ref_name/mas.jpg')
      console.log(temp_photo);
      temp_photo.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
      var Photo_url = document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = downloadURL;
    })
  })
})
```

In my HTML i have the following:

```
<div id="images" class=""></div>
```

what this should do is display that one images for each set of data it pulls. Below are console logs (which are repeated for each set of data its pulling)

```
authWrapper: Qe
app_: T {firebase_: Object, isDeleted_: false, services_: Object, tokenListeners_: Array, analyticsEventRequests_: [], …}  
bucket_: "dbucketname"
deleted_: false
maxOperationRetryTime_: 120000
maxUploadRetryTime_: 600000
pool_: G {createXhrIo: function}
requestMaker_: function(e,t,r)
requestMap_: Ze {map: Map, id: -9007454433453423, addRequest: function, clear: function}
service_: nt {bucket_: J, authWrapper_: Qe, app_: T, internals_: it, ref: function, …}
storageRefMaker_: function(e,t)
Qe Prototype
location: J
bucket: "dbucketname"
path_: "ref_name/mas.jpg"
```

In the div it displays 1 row of the following:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app.appspot.com/o/ref_name%2Fmas.jpg?alt=media&token=11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111

**UPDATE 2**

So it got it to work like so

```
database.once("value", function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      var temp_photo = storageRef.child('ref_name/mas.jpg')
      console.log(temp_photo);
      temp_photo.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
        var x = document.createElement("IMG");
        x.setAttribute("src", downloadURL);
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    })
  })
})
```

its looping around each user and displaying the picture as expected.

But when i try to move this logic to put this image into a table, i get the following error:

```
IndexSizeError: The index is not in the allowed range.
```

this is what my table insert code looks like:

```
var occupant = r.insertCell(16).innerHTML = snap.val().occupation;

    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    var temp_photo = storageRef.child('ref_name/mas.jpg')
    temp_photo.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", downloadURL);
      r.insertCell(17).appendChild(x)
    })

var you_smoke = r.insertCell(18).innerHTML = snap.val().smoke;
```

**UPDATE 3 - SOLUTION**

This is what worked for me:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var temp_photo = storageRef.child('ref_name/mas.jpg')
var y = r.insertCell(17).innerHTML = snap.val().photo_url;
temp_photo.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
  var y = r.insertCell(17).innerHTML = '<img src="'+downloadURL+'" width="20" height="20" />';
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RenaudTarnec's help this is the solution that worked:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var temp_photo = storageRef.child('ref_name/mas.jpg')
var y = r.insertCell(17).innerHTML = snap.val().photo_url;
temp_photo.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
  var y = r.insertCell(17).innerHTML = '<img src="'+downloadURL+'" width="20" height="20" />';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the `key` of the [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), you need to do `snap.key`, see the doc for the [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) property.

To get the URL of an image stored in Cloud Storage for Firebase, with the JavaScript SDK, you should use the [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#get-downloadurl) method of a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#get-downloadurl).

Note that this method is asynchrnonous and therefore you need to do as follows:

```
  ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    //console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
```

Which means, in your case, that you should do something along the following lines (If I have correctly understood your data structure):

```
database.once("value", function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    var r = document.getElementById('userTable').insertRow()
    var age = r.insertCell(0).innerHTML = snap.key;
    //var aboutme = r.insertCell(1).innerHTML = snap.val().photourl;
    var photRef = storageRef.child('user_photos/' + snap.key + '/' + snap.val().photourl);
    photRef.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
        var aboutme = r.insertCell(1).innerHTML = downloadURL;
    });
})
```

Comment: I have updated the question with some new code, as I was having difficulties getting your solution to work, although it took me further, just struggling to display the image

Comment: I cannot look into detail at your new code for the moment, but note that to display the image you should use `.src` and not `.innerHTML`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232793/javascript-set-img-src