# Changing src of image by iterating through a list

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I am trying to have an image change every tenth of a second. I have written a script based off other responses on here and it is still not working. Here is the script:

```
var images = Array();
var index = 0;
images = ["rock.png", "paper.png", "scissors.png"];
var opponent = document.getElementById("opps");

setInterval(myMethod, 100);

function myMethod( ){
    opponent.src = images[index];

    if (index <= 1){
        index++;
    }
    else{
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the tag:

```
<img src = "" id ="opps"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript set img src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232793/javascript-set-img-src)

Comment: It does not. I am getting this error: Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null at myMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. To anyone else with this error it is due to having your script run before your html. Run script after your img.

Comment: It's more than that

Comment: @Kenzoid "rock", "paper", "scissors" is three images. The posted code cycles through `index` values of `0`, `1`, `2`. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 1):

You can do `index % images.length` to infinitely loop over the array - when you go over the index, it'll just wrap back around

Also, you should use `let a = []` to create an empty Array. You don't *have to*, but it's good practice - [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Finally, 100 miliseconds is probably a *little* too often to change an image src, about 1 - 5 seconds should be plenty in most cases

```js
var images = ["rock.png", "paper.png", "scissors.png"];
var index = 0;
var opponent = document.getElementById("opps");

setInterval(myMethod, 100);

function myMethod( ){
    opponent.src = images[index % images.length];
    index += 1;
    
    console.log(opponent.src);
}
```

```html
<img src = "" id ="opps"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked, the strings in the `images` array were relative so maybe you didn't have them in your project. I've simplified a few things, first I initialize and declare the `images` array in the same expression, and second, I turned your if statement in `myMethod()` into a ternary expression:

```js
let index = 0
const images = [
  "http://placekitten.com/200/200", 
  "http://placekitten.com/210/210", 
  "http://placekitten.com/220/220"
]

const opponent = document.getElementById("opps");

setInterval(myMethod, 1000)

function myMethod(){
    opponent.src = images[index];

    index = index <= 1 ? index + 1 : 0
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="opps"/>
```